# Nested inner joins with select sql access

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, inner-join

I have two similar questions and I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207094/nested-inner-join-query) is similar to what I need but I can't figure out what it would look like in my cases

**1.** 
I have three tables where the field `dID` connects `fd` to `d` and `dm` to `d`:

```
`fd`: `fID`, `dID` (`fID` and `dID` create the pk together)
`d`: `dID` (pk), `data`
`dm`: `dID`, `type` (`dID` and `type` create the pk together)
```

I am looking for a way to find all records in `d` that fulfill `fID = 'condition1` AND `type = 'condition2'`

Right now I have solved it in the following way (it works, but it is very ugly so I would like to have a nicer solution)

```
Q1: SELECT dID FROM fd WHERE fID = 'condition1'
Q2: SELECT dID FROM dm WHERE type = 'condition2'

SELECT * FROM d WHERE d.dID IN
(SELECT Q1.dID FROM Q1 INNER JOIN Q2 ON Q1.dID = Q2.dID)
```

**2.**
Now I have three tables again. `mID` connects `tm` to `m` and `typeID` connects `m` to `types`:

```
<br>
`tm`: `tmID`, `mID` (pk together)
`m`: `mID` (pk), `mnum`, `typeID`
`types`: `typeID` (pk), `type`
```

So here I am looking for a way to select `type` from `types` and `mnum` from `m` when I have a condition on `tmID`

The following is not correct because I want to be able to select `mnum` and `type` at the same time like: `SELECT types.type, m.mnum FROM ....`. But basically I want to do these selections

```
Q1: SELECT mID FROM tm WHERE tmID = 'condition3'
Q2: SELECT mnum, typeID FROM m WHERE m.mID IN Q1
Q3: SELECT type FROM types WHERE typeID IN Q2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first query you just have to merge the conditions into one single query:

```
SELECT dID FROM fd WHERE fID = 'condition1' AND type='condition2'
```

For the second query, you can join all three tables together and apply the condition:

```
SELECT types.type
FROM tm INNER JOIN (m INNER JOIN types ON m.typeID = types.typeID) ON tm.mID = m.mID
WHERE tm.tmID='condition3';
```